# Regex for prices, skipping over commas

Tags: regex

I have a real hard time understanding regular expressions, but I was able to hack together this to help me find prices in a string: `/\$(\d*\.?\d+?)/`

This works fairly well, as it will match things such as $1000.00 or $100 or $100.00 - the problem I'm having is dealing with things in the thousands. As $1,000.00 will only match $1.

Is there a way to skip over the commas and simply keep going until the decimal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use this pattern instead:

```
\$\d{1,3}(?:,?\d{3})*(?:\.\d{2})?
```

note that i have supposed that you have always two digits after the period. You can easily change this if you need.

Comment: your pattern matches $100,.00 as well

Comment: @gramonov: no :) :) :) :) :) :) :) :) :) :)

Comment: you mean three digits after the comma, though ;)